# popen("ls", r) in unix returning strange characters

Tags: c, unix, popen

I'm writing program in c to store the file names in the current directory in a string for later use. it compiles and executes without crashing and as far as i can tell works as intended except the string ends up being an indecipherable mix of alphanumeric characters and these strange dots "▒~▒▒ c▒▒ c▒llsestr2▒)test.c"  what is it? why does it happen? how can I fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


main() {
    FILE *p;
    char ch[1024];
    char files[1024];
    p = popen("ls","r");
    sleep(1);
    if( p == NULL)
    {
        puts("Unable to open process");
    }
    while(fgets(ch, 1024, p) != NULL);
    {
    strcat(files, ch);
    sleep(1);
    }
    printf("%s", files);
    pclose(p);   
    }
```

Comment: You never initialized `files`, so you can't use `strcat()` on it.

Comment: `files` contains garbage when you `strcat` to it. But in order to work it has to be a valid string

Comment: Initialize it with `char files[1024] = "";`.

Comment: Also, you'll overflow if the total length of all the filenames (including newlines between them) is more than 1024 characters.

Comment: Why spawn `ls` when the C library has `readdir`?

Comment: Do you really want that semicolon after the `while (...)`?